# Javascript Error While Creating Universal "next()" and "prev()" Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write programs for easy universal application to cycle through images, but have it a snag. Currently working with HTML and Javascript, the codes are as follows:

```js
//JS

    var sliderNum = 0;

    function next(array, index, String) {
        var slider = document.getElementById(String);
        index++;
        if(index >= array.length) {
            index = 0;
        }
        slider.src = array[index];
    }

    function prev(array, index, String) {
        var slider = document.getElementById(String);
        index--;
        if(index < 0) {
            index = array.length-1;
        }
        slider.src = array[index];
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Page Title</title>
     </head>
     <body>
            <div>
                <button onclick="prev(img, sliderNum, 'slider')"> Prev </button>
                <img id="slider" src="http://www.sololearn.com/uploads/slider/1.jpg" width="200px" height="100px"/>
                <button onclick="next(img, sliderNum, 'slider')"> Next </button>
            </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is with the arg 'index'. When the variable ('sliderNum') is used directly within the functions, the buttons work fine, but when used indirectly via the arg, they don't cycle properly. This is annoying, and makes the ability to more universally apply the functions more problematic. What's the problem with the logic, because I want to make these functions work so I never need to write them again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EXPLANATION: In JavaScript most things are Object(even Functions), **Primitive Data Types**(string, number, boolean, null and undefined) are not Objects and they are **immutable**,which means that once created they cannot be modified.

*Primitive Data Types are passed By Value and Objects are passed By Reference.*

In your case, you are passing `sliderNum` in `next` function. That is like assigning value of sliderNum to index. So whenever you change the index, original sliderNum will not change.

**With Objects, =operator works by reference.** In you case, if you create a Object and pass in function and if even you change the value of localObject, it will change the origiba object value as well.

in your HTML

```
<button onclick="next(infoObject)"> Next </button>
```

and in your script

```
var infoObject = {'img': [], 'sliderNum':0};
function next(localObject) {
        var slider = document.getElementById(String);
        localObject.sliderNum++;
        console.log(`localObject.index is --> ${localObject.sliderNum}`);// this will print 1
        console.log(`infoObject.index is --> ${infoObject.sliderNum}`);// this will also print 1
}
```

OLD ANSWER: Because you are passing them in function, they are limited to function scope, Define them outside

```
var sliderNum = 0;
var index = 0;
function next(array, String) {
    var slider = document.getElementById(String);
    index++;
    if(index >= array.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    slider.src = array[index];
}

function prev(array, String) {
    var slider = document.getElementById(String);
    index--;
    if(index < 0) {
        index = array.length-1;
    }
    slider.src = array[index];
}
```

Comment: I get what you're saying, but 'sliderNum' (which *is* outside the scope of the function) is no different than global array 'img' (which I didn't include in the code because it wasn't necessary) which is also outside the functions. I wrote code that allowed me to alter the contents of global array 'img' without having this weird quirk. Isn't the arg simply supposed to serve as a stand-in, a variable for the value that will eventually replace it in the HTML when calling the functions?

Comment: NO, because you are not modifying the array in function. You are just playing with index and when passed in function and you update it wil be limited to function scope only.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: I get what you and Mozilla are saying, but I'm not declaring the variable within the function (at least not like the example). I'm simply using 'index' as a placeholder *for* the global variable that is *going* to be used by the function later like with 'img' and 'array' as shown in the provided code.

Comment: I want you to take a look at W3 Schools and what they have to say here. I get that it is regarding PHP, but arguments *are* variables, making the code's inability to work VERY weird. This is their comment:

"Information can be passed to functions through arguments. An argument is just like a variable.

Arguments are specified after the function name, inside the parentheses. You can add as many arguments as you want, just separate them with a comma."

...and this is the link:

"https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp"

Comment: Edited the answer wit the explanation about passed by Value and Passed by Reference.

Comment: Hey, Narendra. Implemented this method in my code and got it to work universally as intended. I greatly appreciate the explanation. The concept is still confusing even though I understand how it works, because it is strange it doesn't work the other way around like with img. Thanks again.